# Istio Keeps On Showing TcpProxyValidationError Errors

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

I initially created an EnvoyFilter to apply `idle_timeout` of `5s` to outbound requests originating from workloads with label `app: mecha-dev`.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: tcp-idle-timeout
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: mecha-dev
  filters:
    - listenerMatch:
        listenerType: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
        listenerProtocol: TCP
      filterName: envoy.tcp_proxy
      filterType: NETWORK
      filterConfig:
        idle_timeout: 5s
```

However, the filter did not work for me and I found out it was because my cluster is using `istio v1.2.5` which is a very old version and does not support `EnvoyFilters` properly and the envoy API for the same have been deprecated.

Therefore, I deleted the `EnvoyFilter` using `kubectl`.

But, even after deletion of the filter the `istio-proxy` sidecar containers keep on showing me the following error again and again:

```
[2021-05-11 11:59:14.109][22][warning][config] [external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_subscription_impl.cc:73] gRPC config for type.googleapis.com/envoy.api.v2.Listener rejected: Error adding/updating listener(s) 10.155.0.113_443: Proto constraint validation failed (TcpProxyValidationError.StatPrefix: ["value length must be at least " '\x01' " bytes"]): idle_timeout {
  seconds: 5
}
```

I deleted the pods and re-created new ones but this error keeps on showing up. Is there anything else I need to clean up or delete to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

As you already realised, `EnvoyFilter` was not yet supported in Istio *1.2.5*.
Using old, unsupported versions of software exposes you to these types of cases. In this situation, your best bet would be to upgrade to newer version of Istio and recreate `EnvoyFilter` the way you initially wanted.

Also, please be aware that `filterName` `envoy.tcp_proxy` is [depracted](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/version_history/v1.14.0#deprecated) since envoy *1.4.0*. You should use `envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy` instead.